# Return a list with members that belong to another list

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables:

1. Users data with **PK** `UserId`
2. UsersOrders with **FK** `UserID`

I want to do LINQ query to give me a list of users with member that is the list of the user orders.

I've tried:

```
var myNestedData = (from ub in db.Users
   join ah in db.UsersOrders  on ub.UserId equals ah.UserId
   into joined
   from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
   group j by new { ub.UserId, ub.UserName, ub.UserPhone, ub.Approved } into grouped
   where grouped.Key.Approved  == true
   select new 
   {
      UserId= grouped.Key.UserId,
      UserName = grouped.Key.UserName, 
      UserPhone = grouped.Key.UserPhone,
      Orders = grouped
   }).ToList();
```

The problem is that I'm getting inside `Orders` an `Object<a,UsersOrders>`, which I don't expect.

Is this the right way to approach a solution in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you should be able to keep this simple:

```
     var myNestedData = (from u in db.Users
                         where u.Approved == true
                         select new
                         {
                             User = u,
                             Orders = u.UserOrders
                         }).ToList();
```

You are trying to get a list of all the Approved users and that users orders.  Am I missing something?

ALso the name of u.UserOrders will depend on how you have configured your mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
Orders = grouped.ToList()
```

To see if it's a *potential* performance issue, look at the SQL that is generated to see if it is an N+1 scenario (meaning it runs one query for the parent record and N queries for the child records.

I say *potential* because while may not be the fasted method, it may not be an *issue*.  If there is no *noticeable* performance problems I wouldn't worry about it and instead focus on making the app better by improving the experience, which may include improving the perfornamce of *other* areas of the map.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UsersOrders  ] ToList[UsersOrders  ](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[UsersOrders  ])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression